# How to resolve 'property-no-unknown' error in StyleLint?

Tags: wordpress, sass, stylelint

I have a Wordpress project where Webpack and the StyleLint plugin are being used.

The problem is when compiling sass, it shows this error where it says it doesn't recognize the 'aspect-ratio' property that I'm using in my styles:

`Unexpected unknown property "aspect-ratio" property-no-unknown`

I tried adding 'ignoreProperties' to the config in the .stylelintrc.js file but it didn't work and it kept showing the error.

```
module.exports = {
  'extends': 'stylelint-config-standard',
  'rules': {
'no-empty-source': null,
'string-quotes': 'double',
'at-rule-no-unknown': [
  true,
  { 
    'ignoreProperties': [
      'aspect-ratio'
    ] 
  },
  {
    'ignoreAtRules': [
      'extend',
      'at-root',
    ],
   },
  ],
 },
};
```

How could I fix it? (I'm not very knowledgeable in StyleLint and this project was started by someone else.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aspect-ratio` is [a known property in the latest version of Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/demo#N4Igxg9gJgpiBcICGACYKkGcAOMwBcBaAJyXwEsJ4UBGAehoG4UBfAHQDsQAaETATw74kADwThMmHuAgcAZuQDm44JxQo2IYgFcANjEybqqjuvWakHDhGEVZha4W0cA1tYDuHIynw6Y3NTMLIh19BwgnVw8vBB8-ANMgkAAjXQgwF3DCGABbbHx+b19tf0DzGTTiLPIOADckXXIoQgALGBEi+LKNGRycmCEs3PzC2OLSxPKwbUx8CBzCbGIIXGICrJzySRrFQnqquWcCShjqcYSzHtgwXSRSOw5CVPTMxyhtbEawMhhCadn5otlqsKAZOiULklrrd7icnmkMll3p9yN98L8lisYGtyGDYgBtbrqc5EtCk8pKazEGDeQmTS5JSAcTB4bQUWq-ZFfH6YQjucj4FqEKDkORybEDIj1XQlQwgckoAC6pPY9MVkPK0LuZDhz0RjkwLQgaxalmamJB-EIEA5xGITTxZy69M0clkRDkSE2uitbw+3PRDi9jriEO6rvdhE93t9EU22w4u0UA2xqKjXvIPsILhg-Hcxqg4Iml1dRwefwaYCyzhwSDAMGaWPuxqLGp6hw4x3sjQ4MDuhEUpBFkqy1mZwg4UDuzRF1K7p1DxaSHfn1aiEE8rfDIBz-DkpH68JeSP9qJ+hBZ+gIxrlTrDLp3uf3weFeBhOvsjnIeWNE-wW4ffoRSQKM+3wbRqSDQ9HGcNwNwXEkHw4YNmkHJpCDuPteS-OoGiaACSxAN4DHrScdgvXAwFFVEBVGO8l3KP0UTRX4yEIb9sF-Eg9BDRDCKYgNfkvPA5mIW9FzbTRHGGdZMAgCD6wIpJpJEXwQJZTZIDSZklMYiIamldCoHk1IhNuQ0-nmfohHEvjlP03DGnNCBMAFOE2I4rjQhpMZnX4-S7RgRQ9H7dwWgFAxsDrHz6MkkALWxdYYPXTdfPvQjhOvKpsBZbRjL+czsIiWDol0npMtExZcvymB9Gsohkrg1LYu3CrjUIApcDXJqFzpBkJNJEx+opRQqRilA+uGqYZjmBZatySU5QVZV6XUVVLnVVrfHIxxe3cHtxrs8pnAFbrSrShiegabBTT2BoSnCWwTlpUlNFWUjhGTTQ23UIbhs0dp63yAAFYFEtxcTJqmzQVjrWjvoVcoFF0XRrSiqiCgR1aGVdNJoDRuHMZ4RHyrmbACYx0YfpxvhfAgHMKfh+VsfUFb+vWsxNofNjvOyPJ1gOp4YDdakXuxixdHcJB+Dlam-v6gGRCB-8CRJzQ9RcfRJAwuR0SqTAX2Qw8Na12W1ZABQxIagx0ULZmpq56GQEpY1xqh-7kF17FLL6SVNGWlVukdpIeZ4qDfm+FlvE0NJ3GxLHCNDsIjaE9HWK94ho+QSXpd5VzEzCA6E5DkIw8cDlJ3apZhfIDoLripOhNyVEIG0hwYH2mp071rOGilmXi-KDWCpc8jklIes+ZGQhBeSYXXaz3tbUHnph5uUfEyeCffj2wWkAz3uc4H4mHzXtJ892cfovbzveyFkXxol-veRyPQKBnruV-VhFMnXi+t+vrWSec8H6H2fheHYhdP4n0IsPLEHAx7bxvnvA+sQn650IK-XQ78i4wKSHA3ACDN5X0nkA7u8c0HZ3ARfKBvYv4pB-mjAYiDAFp3vgvShfdc70K0u1Fc5ZrBPVkFnHI0BsQxDirwqobQRAVijpQ2OFDJGt3ajImeAxFCCizoaX8PCrIjhklaWe89Raq3FlQ7heDLjyxpoDGA+QxZTSRuQK27dZgNn9izJU1MRpjUcU4zQsx+D6B7EQSAfQzRLS8WzBkHNWbKN9oMMKEUyHsWZA6MBljJEzUBAlNYVpDEfzviAjh1B3blC4cfOWCpFbK38U7fees-g5IWHkomPjlwuNmG422niHYdM0C7UxZTzaNO9uE+qK8FbO3SbACBBdfizx-n04aMTLhxO8duf4s1MENnICBKK+A9a9VeiAAAegACnxCBAAXoqa5hAbkAAZCAAE5FQACoACUFzCAPOeW8xUABqL5HyAAkUyyReM0P0SQSAvqUIAKIiEorbFA2z5goCAvslAABHEoxB+AoBTj4CAKA54oBzMkJAyQ5E+UDmqbJAJWlg3yYsMgxz6lJEuf8+5tyXnvO+b8-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-CJNqcrcAkxNbHX2uU52csHbZEga7uJJ5FnVwpzpVnRR5m9MqceFFakQg2gsmwh3QW5GMlaYwQp99on9P2G85KPzBgjO-GC7AP9to80FvoVFx4EFUacfROJHjGXPN8nCnljTWafXP3oS0B6sBBwwB3jYQNvcFn0M8msR6TXKGzHtImVrwmhCdeoAAJjiruZ8h42pVEEYNno71JTwt+M4U2fIBThUeLufMxBGwcCzBrehY2Dzxec4czl8HCI8tuXyx5oqhV-P5YCkF4KoM1JALKhbWclUiRVQd4MxLfvaopVSmlLm6PrKDnFfQiZBSPOxBEZKAoyows7bZjD3h+3bmswm9RUOWho6Gw5jHeyQLijIBBCOk6EuRooXJyronsXE7AmTyybdPUmZSwBmVRPQKk8gs5o1rmNwc6SPT7n4FeeGwiBXYy2VqQKDri1QCXOSdi4xJhXzBh4upKS6Z-97nFfAVF0z0giZfhNjIO1R91OKtZMJwb5XRvLDJiYc2fWP62ehZnfr-ZhB8XYiMVsMJhnpNU9k9by9caItxRF77wlH9umScp5pmnGCqOR9t97mP-v4+GdZ2B7NZn6HSX5laND67oEK-8tkVuxWUlp0R0ROMWx-4DEbHIC88liCT2k-Xjg2gchzyqPoJAIpN43Nhxev1-E+8D8wZ26uVFXLCNiAAFjir3-v3tHCjp7LsMfyx93pSSBqkH2a3P0OP+XFvVdZe13r7zFHvxf1nZDvJiPunsbQfKLBlWIyvHONcRhr0qDgyGajTEMm7IRk0hMn7MARtAxpzHFJNhhEcvaMkGyI-hPDmPgHnGwtruznrhlPNFlMgdtGgYGGbpVJbqHlJLrvQkgRyqgegc7ubq7lWu7vnrQaJvQSgeQGQb8LltxjmpPkkEgd2trCduIlyuUBdo8ldgCoKj8ndtdg9uKs9tCq9gYHKjWp9gQCqmIZgCgJNqSjqnqgaiDvAfEq1EQZVOEskDUCwYnuVgVlwdYe1LYfYZQW7nnmHsIeUEgbAJgKRFOIMO4chJVLtPYGQvXkgehBIcQCcuYjIXciKoCrdike8o9hKtUuoW9vKj0DoWik0IYa4cQMYYDvqsDvzrAawODlYVeJVI0NnhEsghGknj4XQSUXHoHs0bnvhjQfWogZ0Zjg-vZoMfUe1JfpXDLjXPLgNA+EgYIh1g8FnOEp8O0B0eMdlNVBEPoSfj0Gfi4ZsVVDAHlDsYVOyj5oKBrjgdfHgQ6pwWMSJFXNsdkHVCOFUafoLgQSIZ0TlCcTVG8SERTtNssZQsZNoKZBsU8VUJ1BHFgDWgcYgUaCaGaDupaFkMus4MEVKPdLxAen4dtJvAIfliAOCZCaJidGEvCQLnHN8eUNKA9BtgWHsTHF8fQgyW2k0R2i0Wek4UIbGtgopjetuByV0cRuptfG0TxmltRoWg+KKY0d0dyb0d6v0ULvSbiWKcMcXgmqMSKZqZMdLkCDMUWIEKqCwCACwEAA). You should update your copy of Stylelint to the latest version using:

```
npm install -D stylelint@latest
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ignoreProperties` secondary option, but you should use it on the `property-no-unknown` rule rather than the `at-rule-no-unknown` one as it's a property, not an at-rule:

```
module.exports = {
  'extends': 'stylelint-config-standard',
  'rules': {
'no-empty-source': null,
'string-quotes': 'double',
'at-rule-no-unknown': [
  true,
  {
    'ignoreAtRules': [
      'extend',
      'at-root',
    ],
   },
  ],
 },
 'property-no-unknown': [
  true,
  { 
    'ignoreProperties': [
      'aspect-ratio'
    ] 
  },
 ]
};
```